# FCFG error in NLTK, Python. Grammar Issue

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, context-free-grammar

A line in a feature-based context free grammar I am writing in Python using NLTK gives me the following error.

```
Error parsing feature structure
ADJ[SEM=<\x.x(\y.(some(y))>] -> 'some'
         ^ Expected logic expression
```

I thought the expression after `SEM=` was a logic expression.

Comment: Try rewriting the expression after SEM by (enclosing it entirely in parentheses) or writing \x y. instead of a nested expression. NLTK has unclear rules about parentheses in lambda expressions.

Comment: I tried several variations but they all still return "Expected logic expression" and all types of errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error comes from how NLTK implements types lambda calculus.

```
 \x.x(\y.some(y))
```

It expects lowercase letters to have type `<e>` and uppercase letters to have type `<e,t>`. That is to say that lowercase letters cannot represent predicates.

The following parses: \X.X(\y.some(y))

As an aside, one represents the concept of "some" in "some X are Y" with a conjunction as follows:

```
 \X Y.(X(x) & Y(x))
```

In words, *some X are Y* is logically equivalent to *there are some items have both X and Y quality*.